# Two different column and between query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

My Table

```
id  Type        date              
2  Expense      2017-09-07
3  Expense       2017-09-07
5  Expense       2017-09-06
6  Income        2017-09-06
2  Income        2017-09-07
3  Income        2017-09-07
5  Income        2017-09-05
6   Expense      2017-09-04
```

I Need This Result in one select query 
 Where Expense  and between Date ( 2017-09-06 and 2017-09-07 )

```
id  Type        date              
2  Expense       2017-09-07
3  Expense       2017-09-07
5  Expense       2017-09-06
```

Comment: and what did you tried so far ?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `Type`='Expense'
AND `date` BETWEEN '2017-09-06 00:00:00' AND '2017-09-07 00:00:00'
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -1):

Its just a simple `WHERE` clause at the end of your query, look [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) to get a better understanding. Its one of the most basic but important parts of SQL

Add

```
WHERE Type = 'Expense' 
AND date BETWEEN '2017-09-06' AND '2017-09-07'
```

After the `FROM` part of your `SELECT`

Comment: Thanxx...you so much

Comment: @MunawarAkram no worries, W3Schools is good for learning the basics of SQL and remember to upvote answers if you found them helpful

Answer (score -1):

It's simple:

```
select * from yourtable t where t.type='Expense' and t.date BETWEEN '2009-06-25' AND '2009-07-01';
```

Comment: Thanxx...you so much

Answer (score -1):

You can use this.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE (Type = 'Expense') AND (date BETWEEN('2017-09-06' AND '2017-09-07')) ORDER BY date DESC
```